# Retrieving data from two Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have an Activation model that belongs to User. I'm trying to display information of the activation that the user has submitted in the views, but I'm not sure how to do this. For example,

```
class Activation < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
validates :user_id, presence: true
validates :dealer_store, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
validates :customer_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
validates :customer_phone_number, presence: false, length: { maximum: 10 }

class User < ApplicationRecord
has_many :activations
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
```

I am able to get data from the user of the activations with the user id like so

`<%= activation.user.dealer_store %>`

How would I obtain the customer_phone_number of the activation of the user? I seem to be missing something

You may find it here https://bitbucket.org/QuriouslyStrong/sample_app

Comment: `activation.user.dealer_store` - this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Since a user has many activations you will need to first determine which activation number you want. Say it's the users first activation it would be `user.activations.first.customer_phone_number`

If you already have the activation instance you're looking for you can just do `activation.customer_phone_number`

Having several `activations` sounds odd to me so maybe you're looking to do a has_one & belongs_to relationship instead of a many to one relationship but can't say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to be able to identify which activation you are interested in as all the user's activations will be returned in an array.

```
<%= user.activations[0].customer_phone_number %>
```

Would give you the info for the first activation associated with the user... or, if you wanted to detail all the varying phone numbers associated with all the Activations, you would need to iterate through each of the user's Activations via a block:

```
<% user.activations.each do |act| %>
  <li><%= act.customer_phone_number %></li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking current user's customer phone number then you can try this.

```
<% current_user.activations.each do |a| %>
  <%= a.customer_phone_number %>
<% end %>
```

Also can you try this,
If you have object of user then you can use user object

```
<% user.activations.each do |a| %>
  <%= a.customer_phone_number %>
<% end %>
```